# Force Dropbox OAuth 2 Login Page to Mobile Mode

Tags: ios, oauth, dropbox, dropbox-api

I'm adding the ability for users to log into their Dropbox account from a web view in an iPad app via OAuth 2.

The web view in question is presented in a small modal view controller, and as a result of Dropbox.com rendering the OAuth login page in the standard desktop mode, the content is very small.

Is there a URL parameter to force the Dropbox OAuth 2 page to display in its mobile mode? If so, what is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that page doesn't offer any such parameter. The only officially supported parameters for the Dropbox API OAuth 2 /authorize page are those in the documentation here:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/docs#oa2-authorize

Comment: Dang it. I feared as much. Thanks anyway! I'll see if there's an alternative way. Maybe changing the request's user agent to match an iPhone's.